# Word-under-cursor highlighting *and* multi-highlighting in Vim

Tags: terminal, syntax-highlighting, vim, vim-plugin

I am currently using two plugins which work very well independently, but which interfere with one another slightly:

[Mark](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666)
and 
[HiCursorWords](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4306)

It appears that both of these plugins use a similar method which causes the highlight styles to interfere with one another.

I set the highlight for the word under the cursor to be simply to underline the word (I tried just bolding it, but that is just a little too subtle and too easy to overlook), without changing its color or anything. This works wonderfully by itself as all words continue to use the color from their syntax highlighting.

However once Mark is also enabled, the highlights for the marked words are overridden by the cursor-word highlight. Since the properties of the highlights do not intersect it should be theoretically possible to have it so that the Mark-highlights stay the same and when the cursor is on any of them they should simply gain the underline in addition to whatever other styles they already have applied.

Is this a possibility given that these plugins use `matchadd()`? Is it simply a matter of adding this feature to the Mark plugin so that we can multiplex the highlight styles to account for the need to layer **3** styles simultaneously? The big question is, is it even possible to layer 3 styles simultaneously?

(I know it's possible to layer two, because e.g. HiCursorWords can underline a word in a comment, this causes the word (I set my comments to be italic) to become italic and underlined; and e.g. with Mark, the marked word inside a comment becomes highlighted (background color changed, foreground color changed, and stays italic) -- the question is can we apply BOTH in order to result in a comment word being displayed with background/foreground colors changed, underlined, and still italic, when my cursor is on it and it is Marked?)

**Edit:** It appears that `matchadd()` will simply override any previous style set by `matchadd()`. So if I can get the HiCursorWords plugin to check if the word is *already* highlighted by Mark, then it can go and set a special third style (which will be both highlighted and underlined). Hopefully there is a way.

Furthermore, I noticed that the `/` search highlight style overrides all the other `matchadd` highlights. So my underline from the word-highlight will be overridden by it. It'd also be nice if I can get the underline to show for this situation as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there's no *layering* of highlight groups. You basically have the highlighting from the syntax plugin, `matchadd()`, and the current search pattern. (There's a pending patch that allows to have `:syntax` commands add / remove attributes; you may find the discussion on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).)

As the *HiCursorWords* plugin uses `matchadd()` like *Mark*, you could try my alternative [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320), which also offers highlighting of the word under the cursor, but uses the default search highlighting instead.

Speaking of search highlighting and `matchadd()`, you can influence which goes on top via the optional `{priority}` argument to `matchadd()` (which must be > 0 to go on top).